# Getting error : [tcl] expected integer but got "r+", how to override?

Tags: r

I'm trying to connect r to my weight balance through a USB port, but every time I try to, I am hit with the error ' [tcl] expected integer and got "r+" '

here is my code

```
require (tcltk)

Loading required package: tcltk 

Tcl('set serial [open /dev/cu.usbserial COM4 r+]' )'
```

> Error in structure (External(.C_dotTcl, ...), class = "tcl0bj") :
> [tcl] expected integer but go "r+".

COM4 being the usb port it needs to connect to, however for some reason the r+ is proving problematic.

I've tried removing the r+, but without it, I get an invalid access mode, I've tried putting the spaces in different locations but the r+ is still not an expected integer. I've also tried using different usb ports on my laptop, but so far no luck.

Comment: You should state what OS you are using.  `/dev/cu.usbserial ` looks like Unix-alike, `COM4` looks like Windows.